# How can I create a "Child function" in a child class that is a function with both the parent's function AND the Child's function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know the title sounds a bit gibberish, but I just don't know what it's called. What I'm trying to do is to create a class with a function, and then create a child class with a "child function" which, when I call it, will run both the parents version of the function and the child's version.
I tried to google it and search on StackOverflow, but as I said, I just don't know what it's called so I didn't find anything of interest, I don't even know if it's possible.

Example:

```
class Parent:
    def function(self):
        print("parent class")

class Child(Parent):
    def function(self):
        print("child class")

p = Parent()
c = Child()

p.function()
c.function() #How can I make this print "parent class" AND "child class"?
```

Also, this is my first Stack Overflow question, so if I accidentally break any rules, please tell me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is `super(Child, self).function()` before printing "child class". Good luck. :)

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Also, would it be appropriate to call this a "child function"?

Comment: I think in C-style programming languages, a function that can be added to / modified (*overloaded*) by a child class is called a *virtual* function.

Answer (score 2):

In child:

```
def function(self):
    super(Child, self).function()
    ...
```

Comment: Note: in Python2.x, super only works for new-style classes so you'll need to specify `Parent` inherits from `object`